# Need to explode a string before return it with ajax to a select/option dynamic

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, getjson

So, i got a pretty bad database that i CAN'T transform.

The string is 5numbers like: 180,2345,123,5643,23534

I need to put those numbers(need to explode somehow) in a select option like this:

```
<select name="hotel" id="hotel" class="fieldbackend">
<option value="403">403</option>
<option value="880">880</option>
<option value="983">983</option>
<option value="648">648</option>
</select>
```

Presently i got this result:

```
<select name="hotel" id="hotel" class="fieldbackend">
<option value="undefined">undefined</option>
<option value="undefined">undefined</option>
<option value="undefined">undefined</option>
<option value="undefined">undefined</option>
<option value="403,880,983,648">403,880,983,648</option>
</select>
```

There is my source code:

```
<select class="fieldbackend" id="destination" name="destination">
     <option value="">-- Destination --</option>
</select>

<select class="fieldbackend" id="hotel" name="hotel">
     <option value="">-- Hôtel --</option>
</select>
```

There is my JS:

```
$(function(){
    $('#destination').change(function(){
        $.getJSON('/dev/select2.php', {'destination': $(this).val()}, function(data) {
            var items = '';
            $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                items += '<option value="' + val['deHotels'] + '">' + val['deHotels'] + '</option>';
            });

        $('#hotel').html(items);
        });
    });
})
```

Finaly there is my php code:

```
$requete = "SELECT DISTINCT deHotels FROM sirev_Dests WHERE deDestName = '". $_GET['destination'] ."' ORDER BY deDestName";
    $connect = mysql_connect("&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&","&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&","&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&");

    mysql_select_db("&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&", $connect);

    $res = mysql_query($requete) or die(mysql_error());
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res, true)) {
        $items = explode(',',$row['deHotels']);
        array_push($items, $row);
    }
die(json_encode($items));
```

There is a screen of the result:
http://nsa29.casimages.com/img/2012/06/01/120601072406136633.jpg

Sorry for my english, im from quebec city.

Any one can help me to figure it out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res, true)) {
  array_push($items, $row['deHotels']);
}
```

Comment: No more results, no undefined and no string, hotel still empty

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP code should look like this:

```
$res = mysql_query($requete) or die(mysql_error());
if ($res) {
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($res);
    $items = explode(',', $row);
    die(json_encode($items));
}
```

Since you are only select 1 row from database, no need to loop the query result. And use `explode()` to convert the string `'180,2345,...'` into `array('180','2345',...)`.

And in your js, replace `val['deHotels']` with just `val`:

```
$.each(data, function(key, val) {
   items += '<option value="' + val + '">' + val + '</option>';
});
```

Comment: Sound's great, I understand your logic, but still doesnt work, any tip? I got no interaction and no value in my select hotels when I test it.

Comment: IT WORKS !!!!! if ($res) {
  $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
  $items = explode(',', $row['deHotels']);
  die(json_encode($items));
 }

Comment: Yes. Or you can use `mysql_fetch_row()`. See my edited answer.

Comment: Damnn didnt realise that i need to fletch those numbers, to names of the hostel in an other tab -_-', i need to put the number in value and  we should see the name in option... the other table is like: ID, name. So should i make an other file.php? Or can I do this query in the same php and push to my js 2 informations?